# Do until EOF missing the final entry in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the following code I am setting a True/False field in order to print reports using the user's input
but the last record is not printed,

If I comment out the last loop (the loop to set all to false) I get all records printed but I need to set them all back to False

```
Sub PrintReports()
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
 
    ' Prompt user to enter start date
    startDate = InputBox("Enter start date (mm/dd/yyyy):")

    ' Prompt user to enter end date
    endDate = InputBox("Enter end date (mm/dd/yyyy):")

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM CustomerT WHERE ExpiryDate >= #" & startDate & "# AND ExpiryDate <= #" & endDate & "#")

rst.MoveFirst

Do Until rst.EOF Or rst.BOF
  rst.Edit
  rst("ToPrint") = True
  rst.Update
  rst.MoveNext
Loop

DoCmd.OpenReport "2DateReports", acViewPreview, , , acNormal

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF Or rst.BOF
  rst.Edit
  rst("ToPrint") = False
  rst.Update
  rst.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a split multiple simultaneous users database? Users will conflict with each other in setting this yes/no field. Don't need to loop recordset to set all records back to false, just run an UPDATE action SQL. Why do you need this anyway? Just apply the same date range filter criteria to report in the OpenReport method. Also, validating input to InputBox is not easy. Better to use textboxes on form for user input. This entire procedure could be reduced to about 3 lines of code.

Comment: Also, consider: `ExpiryDate BETWEEN #" & startDate & "# AND #" & endDate & "#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a timing issue - perhaps the report hasn't finished printing.

Try this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "2DateReports", acViewPreview, , , acNormal
DoEvents
Stop         ' Press F5 to continue. To be removed after test.
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much. I thought I was going mad